# Creating a trigger gives "function does not exist" error in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'm working on a project right now where I'm trying to build a trigger that updates a column "lastedit" (in the table Person), which is a timestamp storing when the last change was made to the table in the schema specified in the trigger creation (in this case Certifications).

Now, my problem is that when I try to create the trigger, after creating the function "update_lastedit()", it gives me an error saying that the function does not exist. I think I might have a mismatch in my function somewhere, but I cannot seem to find it.

Could any of you help me out? I'm running PostgreSQL 9.5.5. Please let me know if I need to give a more extensive explanation, this is my first question, so I might have overlooked something important.

My code for the trigger and the function are as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_lastedit() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$update_edit$
BEGIN
    UPDATE ovsoftware.person
    SET lastedit = now();
END;
$update_edit$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and

```
CREATE TRIGGER cert_edit_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON ovsoftware.certifications
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_lastedit();
```

The exact error:

```
SQL fout:

ERROR:  function update_lastedit() does not exist
In statement:

CREATE TRIGGER cert_edit_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON ovsoftware.certifications
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_lastedit();
```

Comment: please update post with exact error - your provided code sample is ok

Comment: Done, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Just to make sure - unlike the order they are presented in the post, you create the function before attempting to create the trigger, right?

Comment: Yes, I have created the function first, then tried to create the trigger. I will switch them in the original post to prevent confusion.

Comment: could not reproduce it in 9.6.3. And in general - code looks ok

Comment: Are you sure that they are in the same database **and** in the same schema? (If they are supposed to be in another schema, but in the same database, you can use fully qualified names everywhere).

Comment: Sidenote: I'm hoping that the trigger body is just some example code. If that would be a real trigger body, every insert or update on `ovsoftware.certifications` would rewrite the whole `ovsoftware.person` table & leave a ton of dead tuples in it (because it updates every row in it).

Comment: Hi pozs, I am certain they are in the same database. They are also both in the same schema (named ovsoftware). The trigger body was actually code I thought worked though. I am going to change that, because now it indeed loops over all entries in the person table, instead of the entry connected to the certification that is updated. I'll look into that, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: You want: `new.lastedit := now();` in the trigger, not an UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use a fully qualified name for the function as follows: `ovsoftware.update_lastedit()`. I am not sure why that is the case, as I did not need to do so in other cases.
Either way, the scope apparently did not include the ovsoftware schema, leading to the error.